# Gensim's FastText KeyedVector out of vocab

Tags: gensim, word-embedding, fasttext

I want to use the read-only version of Gensim's FastText Embedding to save some RAM compared to the full model.

After loading the KeyVectors version, I get the following Error when fetching a vector:

`IndexError: index 878080 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 761210`

The error occurs when using words that should be out-of-vocabulary e.g. "lawyerxy" instead of "lawyer". The full model returns a vector for both.

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
model = KeyedVectors.load("model.kv")
model .wv.__getitem__("lawyerxy")
```

So, my assumption is that the KeyedVectors do not offer FastText's out of vacabulary function - a key feature for my usecase. This limitation is not given in the documentation:
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

Can anyone prove that assumption and/or name a fix to allow vectors for "lawyerxy" etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `KeyedVectors` name is (as of `gensim-3.8.0`) just an [alias](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/a47eed80cf225181717cba09761922d4a54027d8/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py) for class `Word2VecKeyedVectors`, which only maintains a simple word (as key) to vector (as value) mapping.

You shouldn't expect FastText's advanced ability to synthesize vectors for out-of-vocabulary words to appear in any model/representation that doesn't explicitly claim to offer that ability.

(I would expect a lookup of an out-of-vocabulary word to give a clearer `KeyError` rather than the `IndexError` you've reported. But, you'd need to show exactly what code created the file you're loading, and triggered the error, and the full error stack, to further guess what's going wrong in your case.)

Depending on how your `model.kv` file was saved, you might be able to load it, with retained OOV-vector functionality, by using the class [`FastTextKeyedVectors`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/a47eed80cf225181717cba09761922d4a54027d8/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L1943) instead of plain `KeyedVectors`.

Comment: Thanks, prefix FastText solved my problem.
``` from gensim.models import FastTextKeyedVectors ``` 
```model = FastTextKeyedVectors .load("model.kv") ```

Comment: For me (as of 2021) this seems to work:    

`from gensim.models import KeyedVectors;`                                               
`kv =  KeyedVectors.load("my_kv_file.kv");`                                                 
`type(kv);`                                                                                         
`# >> class 'gensim.model.fasttext.FastTextKeyedVectors'` . And kv["some_oov_word"] returns something.